# How can I remove the debug banner in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, android-emulator

I'm using `flutter screenshot` and I expected the screenshot to not have a banner, but it has.

Note that I get a `not supported for emulator` message for profile and release mode.

Answer (score 1476, accepted):

On your `MaterialApp` set `debugShowCheckedModeBanner` to `false`.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
)
```

The ***debug*** banner will also automatically be removed on the release build.

Comment: Usage: `return new MaterialApp(
        home: new LoginPage(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        ));`

Comment: do i need to use `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false` on each class means activity ?

Comment: The `flutter` tool's built-in screenshot command also knows how to automatically remove the "debug" banner while taking a screenshot if that's helpful.

Comment: @EricSeidel Not by default it doesn't (Flutter 1.16.4-pre.18 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c8efcb632b (6 weeks ago) • 2020-03-27 22:31:01 -0700
Engine • revision 3ee9e3d378) Is there a trick to enable this?

Comment: Is there any way to show it in release build? I am building a release versions but for dev/production environments

Comment: ehmmm guys it's been outdated but I need to ask. what if I don't have a MaterialApp widget in my project? where should I put the debugshowcheck property? or maybe is there another way around getting rid of that debug text?

Comment: @AlexAngelico no need of `new` keyboard

Comment: @Obink If you are using `WidgetsApp`, `MaterialApp`, or `CupertinoApp`, the process is the same. Otherwise, there should be no debug banner by default. If you wish to have the banner, wrap your tree with a `CheckedModeBanner` widget.

Comment: @Moti Bartov Just show your own little picture?

Answer (score 128):

***Outdated***

- If you are using Android Studio, you can find the option in the Flutter Inspector tab → *More Actions*.

  [image: Android Studio]
- Or if you're using Dart DevTools, you can find the same button in the top right corner as well.

  [image: Dart DevTools]

Comment: Disappeared on the DevTools View, but I have found it through AndroidStudio

Answer (score 81):

Well, this is the simple answer you want.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false
)

CupertinoApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false
)
```

But if you want to go deep with the app (want a release APK file (which doesn't have a debug banner) and if you are using Android Studio then go to *Run* → *Flutter* → *Run 'main.dart' in Release mode*.

Answer (score 51):

If you are using [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), there is an option in the Flutter Inspector to disable it.

Run the project:

[image: Open the Flutter inspector]

[image: Hide the slow banner]

When you are in the Flutter Inspector, click or choose "More Actions."

[image: Picture of the Flutter Inspector]

When the menu appears, choose "Hide Debug Mode Banner":

[image: Picture of Hide Debug Mode Banner]

Comment: This menu and related item doesn't exist in idea 2020.3 and flutter 55.0.3

Answer (score 39):

The debug banner appears only while in development and is automatically removed in the release build.

To hide this there is a need to set `debugShowCheckedModeBanner` to `false`

```
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 35):

## Three ways to remove flutter debug banner:-

##### 1. In the MaterialApp/ScaffoldApp

**Snippet**

```
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
)
```

**OR**

```
ScaffoldApp(
             debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        );
```

---

##### 2.By making release version of your app

> For running release version of your app, use this command

```
flutter run --release
```

> Or if using  real devices rather than emulators or simulators.
> `make a build version of the app`.

```
flutter build apk
```

---

##### 3.BY using dart dev tool to remove debug banner

IN vs code type `ctr+shift+p`in windows and for mac `cmd+shift+p` and use this command to open dart dev tool

```
Dart: Open DevTools
```

[image]

Answer (score 31):

There is also another way for removing the "debug" banner from the Flutter app. Now after a new release there is no `"debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,"` code line in the main .dart file. So I think these methods are effective:

1. If you are using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), then install `*"Dart DevTools"* from extensions. After installation, you can easily find the *"Dart DevTools"* text icon at the bottom of Visual Studio Code. When you click on that text icon, a link will be opened in Google Chrome.  From that link page, you can easily remove the banner by just tapping on the banner icon as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXEmb.png).

NOTE: [Dart DevTools](https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-24/) is a Dart language debugger extension in Visual Studio Code

2. If *Dart DevTools* is already installed in your Visual Studio Code, then you can directly open Google Chrome and open
   the URL *"127.0.0.1: ZZZZZ/?hide=debugger&port=XXXXX"*

*Note*: In this link, replace "XXXXX" by 5 digit port-id (on which your Flutter app is running) which will vary whenever you use the `flutter run` command and replace "ZZZZZ" by your global (unchangeable) 5 digit debugger-id

*Note*: These Dart developer tools are only for the Google Chrome browser

Answer (score 22):

On your MaterialApp set debugShowCheckedModeBanner to false.

```
 MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  )
```

The debug banner will also automatically be removed on release build.

If you are using emulator or real device and you want to check it on release
mode then =>

```
   flutter run release --apk
```

run this command on terminal Android Studio / Vs Code

Answer (score 21):

To remove the Flutter debug banner, there are several possibilities:

1. The first one is to use the *debugShowCheckModeBanner* property in your [MaterialApp](http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) widget.

   Code:

   ```
   MaterialApp(
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   )
   ```

   And then do a hot reload.
2. The second possibility is to hide debug mode banner in Flutter Inspector if you use [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) or [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA).

   [image]
3. The third possibility is to use [Dart DevTools](https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-24/).

Comment: This menu and related item doesn't exist in idea 2020.3 and flutter 55.0.3

Answer (score 17):

Use:

```
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
)
```

This is the code for removing this banner.
The debug banner is due to MaterialApp, e.g., you can see this banner on all that pages that use **MaterialApp**.

There should be at least one MaterialApp in your app on main root.

Answer (score 17):

All other answers are great for Android Studio, but if using Visual Studio Code there is a command you can use to toggle this easily. Open the *command palette* (Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>). Then type *toggle debug-mode banner* as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It's the *app.dart* class property.

It displays a banner, saying "DEBUG" when running in checked mode. MaterialApp builds one of these by default.

For disabling this banner in debug mode also, you can set a Boolean false.

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme:....
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: SplashScreen(),
);
```

In release mode this has no effect.

Answer (score 9):

If you are still in ***debug*** mode, you can switch to ***release*** mode and the banner will be gone.

*[image: release]*

[image]

You can also open the same Run/Debug Configurations window via shortcuts:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, then Press <kbd>0</kbd> and Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.

Now enter `--release`.

Answer (score 6):

If you use `Scaffold` in Return Section so add on Top `MaterialApp` and `Restart`

```
void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
                 debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, 
                 home: Home()),
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way.

For : MaterialApp(
**debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false**
)

For : CupertinoApp(
**debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false**
)

If you are logically handle another flutter components
them you use a bool variable & handle it.
For Example
bool isDebug === false ;

if(isDebug == true)
{
**debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true**
}

else
{
**debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false**
}

Thanks & Enjoy)):

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should [vote it up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score -2):

Just assign `debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false` inside MaterialApp widget.

Comment: How does this differ from other answers - for example, [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73684544/12567365) - which already mention the same solution? The question has already attracted dozens of answers. Any new answer should provide a new solution.

Comment: You simply would not believe how many answers have already been deleted that look exactly like this.  *Please* review the existing answers first before posting and don't duplicate existing information. Thanks!