# I cannot stop the debugger

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to stop debbuger from running and I cannot figure out how. I've read everything here and still nothing. I made a weather app in flutter and I am ready to upload it to google play but I get the error that tells me I need to stop debbuging. Anyone know how to? Notice the debug banner on top right[image: App screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean by "Cannot stop the debugger from running" ?

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893935/how-to-remove-slow-mode-banner-in-flutter-on-android-emulator/48893964#48893964

Comment: I've tried that. It did not work. This is the error I get when uploading to Google Play Console: You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build a release version, using `flutter build apk --release`.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

On your MaterialApp set debugShowCheckedModeBanner to false.

```
 MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  )
The debug banner will also automatically be removed on release build.
```

If you are using emulator or real device and you want to check it on release mode
then =>

```
   flutter run release --apk
```

run this command on terminal Android Studio / Vs Code