# How to take screen shots of mobile debug device running Flutter application in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, screenshot, android-studio-3.0, usb-debugging

Using Android Studio for developing flutter replaces the LogCat console with the run tab.

This works great, but how do I take a screen shot of my debugging device?
Previously I used to expand the LogCat side menu and click on the capture image  button, but now I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: what if you want to record screen ?.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`flutter screenshot` cli command saves a png screenshot. I could not find how to do it in IntelliJ interface, either.

Comment: it saves at root of project i have verified

Comment: It's working, but the ugly debug banner is on the screenshot. Has anyone an idea how I can remove this?

Comment: Here's how to remove the debug banner: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48893964/679553

Answer (score 3):

If using the emulator on mac, `cmd` + `s` should take a screenshot.

Comment: cmd + s saves the project and hot reloads the code.
Unless you're referring to the emulator.
Maybe it works there?

Anyway I need it to work with USB-debugging.

Comment: yes, I'm referring to the emulator when is the active window

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, while running the command `flutter run`, you can always press `s` from your keyboard to take a screenshot. Note that the screenshots are saved on the root of your project folder.

Comment: How can I take it from big screens ?

Answer (score 0):

use adb command

```
adb shell screencap -p location
```

location is where screenshot may save in your device

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a screenshot on your app running on your emulator, then you can just select window of that emulator and press the respective keyboard combinations for screenshot. For example, on Windows, its Windows Key + Alt + prt scrn. You might wanna check for Mac, if you are using one.
On Android Studio, beside your emulator, you will see a vertical panel, which will contain icons of power, camera, home, back, and etc. there click on the camera button to take a screenshot and it saves it to your corresponding folder.

Comment: The problem with screenshots are that they either contain the whole emulator screen with controls and the corners outside of the device, or if you select by dragging they become different sizes each time.
Both makes it hard to use it for Store or promotion related tasks.

Comment: If you don't want to have the edges of the device in your screenshot, then you can also disable Device Frame option in Emulator options, and then take a screenshot.

Comment: Sure, but it would also be different resolutions depending on which screen you are using and what size the emulator is resized to.
Using `flutter screenshot` you get an image that's always the resolution of the device, always cuts the corners equally, never get background artifacts if you happen to select outside of the screen, requires no post processing, will look the same for all developers and all platforms and is able to be automated in scripts.
I think the accepted answer is better in all ways I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, it might have been missing for some time in 2019, but it's there in Android Studio all right. Logcat window, left button bar (look for the overflow button if your window is sized small enough not to fit everything). You have both Screen capture and Screen record buttons all right.

Comment: Yes. However since the last update (or the one before it) all video are recorded in .webM format. Do you know how to change it back to mp4?

Comment: Now, I don't. I never actually used it, or I can't recall, so I probably never realized it, just that it's there... Now that I googled for it, there's already a bug report and issue about this.

Comment: Okay.Thanks for taking the time to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Snipping tool from windows in order to take screenshot just type
Snipping Tool In search Box Of Windows
[HelpFull Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLdGr.png)

Comment: Your answer presupposes the use of an emulator. That is unlikely to be the case for most developers.