# How to remove debug banner inside bloc provider

Tags: flutter

How to remove debug banner inside bloc provider i try it to wrap it by another widget to added it but it doesn't work

```
void main() {
  Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
        
        create: (context) => AppCubit()..createDB(),
        child: MaterialApp(home: HomeLayout()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the Flutter debug banner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893935/how-to-remove-the-flutter-debug-banner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false` is `MaterialApp`'s parameter.

Comment: i don't have MaterialApp

Comment: Your `BlocProvider`'s child is `MaterialApp` at your code.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `BlocProvider` with `MaterialApp` and write `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false` That's will solve your problem.